I'm looking for a science fiction book about an alien world being observed through a lens. The world is inhabited by a race of lobster-like beings
I read about this book in an online list of science fiction novels. I can't remember the title or author, but the premise was intriguing. In the book, an organization tries to shut down the operation of observing this alien world.

The Blind Lake is obviously the right answer but just yesterday I read The Crystal Egg by H. G. Wells written in 1897, about a man with a "lens" of sorts that will show live images of aliens on Mars. The aliens are not lobster-like though.

@pipe Sorta funny, what I thought of—also definitely not right—was Dragon’s Egg. Amusing (to me anyway) that the titles are so similar.

Blind Lake by Robert Charles Wilson. From the wiki article

The novel deals with a government installation at Blind Lake, Minnesota where scientists observe sentient life on a planet 51 light-years away, using telescopes powered by Bose-Einstein condensate-based quantum computers that have advanced beyond human understanding. A sudden and unexplained facility lockdown extends into a long-term quarantine.


Hauser and her fellow scientists observe everyday life in a city of lobster-like aliens, they cannot contact the aliens in any way and do not understand their language.

